# How to map @RequestBody payload to builder class

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, lombok, dto

I have an endpoint that gets RequestMessage as a POST body.

I want to map my payload to my java class that uses Lombok with builder pattern and add another variable(`myAccountId`) to it that is present in my `ParentDto` which my ChildDto extends.

Below is my implementation in method sendMessage but I don't see `myAccountId` added in Request Message.

```
@PostMapping("/sendRequest")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestBody RequestMessage payload) {
    final RequestMessage reqDto = payload;
    reqDto.toBuilder()
        .myAccountId(accId)
        .build();
    publishMesaage(reqDto);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**ChildDTO**:

```
 @Getter
 @ToString
 @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)      
 @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
 @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
 public class RequestMessage extends MyDTO {
 private final String name;

 }
```

**ParentDTO**

```
 @Data
 @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
 public abstract class MyDTO implements Serializable {

 @JsonIgnore private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 protected String myAccountId;

 protected MyDTO() {}


public static int hashCode(Object... objects) {
    return Arrays.deepHashCode(objects);
}

public static boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
    // implementation of equals method
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the return value of the `build()` call?

Comment: What are you exactly sending at request body?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your question is. What is the expected behavior or result, and what is the actual result? Is there a builder method that doesn't exist, or is there a value for the `myAccountId` field that isn't being defined somewhere?

Comment: @knittl I am passing the reqDto to another method publishMesaage(reqDto);

Comment: @catch23 I am sending a RequestMessage json using postman.But that json body doesnot have a field myAccountId .So before passing the reqDTO to publishMessage method I need to modify my reqDto to have myAccountId field which is basically defined in my parent DTO that my child DTO extends.

Comment: @OrganikStreet even with your updated code, you are not using the built object. You are never modifying the original object and you are not making use of the modified object returned by `build()`

Comment: Could you show exactly which JSON are you sending

Comment: I am sending this  {"name" : "foo"}

Comment: @knittl  that is what I want to do i need to modify my original object(the one that i received in the payload).The modification i need is I want to add myAccountId to it and then send it to publishMessage method.I am sending this json body using postman {"name" : "foo"}

Comment: Could you please show me how can I modify my original payload received and pass in the modified object returned by build().

Answer (score 1):

You are never using your newly built object returned by the `build()` method. You need to assign its return value to a reference, so you can use it. Calling methods on the builder does not magically update the original object.

```
@PostMapping("/sendRequest")
public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestBody RequestMessage payload) {
    // 1. get a builder from your payload,
    // 2. modify the builder,
    // 3. store the new instance returned by `build` in variable
    final RequestMessage reqDto = payload.toBuilder()
        .myAccountId(accId)
        .build();
    // 4. pass new instance to your other method
    publishMesaage(reqDto);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```